# How to force sqalchemy float type to real in postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

When I define a column using sqlalchemy I use the float type with syntax like

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float
new_column_name = Column('new_column_name',Float,nullable=True)
```

This seems to default to a **double** in postgres, if I wanted a **real**, is this done through the precision input, or a different type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html?highlight=data%20type#generic-types

```
class sqlalchemy.types.REAL(precision=None, asdecimal=False, decimal_return_scale=None)

    Bases: sqlalchemy.types.Float

    The SQL REAL type.
```

Comment: Ah, that's clear, sorry to have missed that and thank you!